# How to edit environment variables in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have upgraded visual studio project using visual studio 2013 .
ON building project I get many compilation errors as it doesnt find basic c++ includes such as
string, iostream etc

I notice that in properties pages , instead of VC++ directories option there is VC++ environment variables. In those variables there is PATH and INCLUDE which are pointing to non existing folder paths. I want to update those variables to point to correct folder paths. But I cannot do it as field are greyed out.

Does anyone know how to enable editing those environment variables ? thanks![Following is snapshot of property pages][1]

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at the project file (using a text editor)

Comment: Snapshot link is missing from your post.